# How to set fontFamily for all text in the app?

Tags: android

I want every text in the app to be `sans-serif-thin` but I don't know how to change it. I can add `android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"` to a `TextView` and it works great, but I don't want to have to change the code for every TextView in every activity.

I tried adding `<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>` to the `AppTheme` style in `styles.xml` but to no effect.

Comment: Has the theme been applied? You can apply a theme to the entire application by adding `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to the `<application/>` field in the Manifest.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to set fontFamily for all text in the app?

**Solution**

If you want use just `android-default-font` (sans, serif, mono).

Try this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item>
</style>
```

**Additional**

If you want to specify a `custom font` as the default font, you can use the [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library. This library is provides various features related to font.

Comment: Yes, this works. 4 minutes until I can accept the answer. This is a really stupid rule, now I have to hang around for 4 minutes instead of getting work done.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set one font for all TextViews in android application you can use this solution. It will override ALL TextView's typefaces, includes action bar and other standard components, but EditText's password font won't be overriden.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
 public void onCreate() {
   TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "SERIF", "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"); // font from assets: "assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf
 }
}
```

Don't forget to add android:name="com.you.yourapp.MyApp" in application tag of Manifest file.

Add in theme in style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
  <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
   <!-- you should set typeface which you want to override with TypefaceUtil -->
   <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Create a class TypefaceUtil.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class TypefaceUtil {

/**
 * Using reflection to override default typeface
 * NOTICE: DO NOT FORGET TO SET TYPEFACE FOR APP THEME AS DEFAULT TYPEFACE    WHICH WILL BE OVERRIDDEN
 * @param context to work with assets
 * @param defaultFontNameToOverride for example "monospace"
 * @param customFontFileNameInAssets file name of the font from assets
 */
 public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
    try {
        final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

        final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Can not set custom font " + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of " + defaultFontNameToOverride);
    }
 }
}
```